# Will and can for typical 'behaviour' of inanimate objects: any difference?

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs

In Michael Swan's *Practical English Usage*, fourth edition, entry number 86, entitled 'typical behaviour, *can*, *could*, *may*, *might*, *will*, *would*', I found this example sentence:

> *Sulphuric acid **will** dissolve most metals.*

Would it be possible to say or write '*Sulphuric acid **can** dissolve most metals.* ? Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: That statement means that sulphuric acid will dissolve a metal IF it comes into contact with it. It's not saying that the acid is going to come into contact with it. Therefore all it's saying is that it CAN dissolve the metal if it comes into contact with it. Replacing "will" with "can" will pretty much mean the same thing. That's not to say that the words "will" and "can" have the same meaning, but in this context it's as I explained.

Comment: *Will* here is about "behavior;" *can* is about property/capacity/capability. They **can** mean different things in different contexts.

Answer (score 1):

Dogs **can** bite you. That doesn't mean that they always **will** bite you. (In fact, they seldom do.)

However, sulphuric acid not only **can** dissolve most metals that are exposed to it but always **will** do so (if given the chance).

Comment: Q: _What **can** dissolve this metal?_  A: _Why, sulphuric acid can!_  versus Q: _What **will** happen if I pour sulphuric acid on this metal?_  A: _Why, it **will** dissolve the metal!_

Comment: How about "Some sharks will eat men"? Like the dogs, they can eat men, but won't always do it… and the use of "will" in the sentence is still correct, and of common use, I think…

Comment: @user58319 Quite right. And *some* dogs, especially rabid dogs, *will* bite you. The more their nature is towards biting, the more applicable the statement is. But *can* and *will* do still mean something different.